# Typical in-vivo protein concentration

Tags: proteins

I am studying RNA-binding proteins involved in RNA granules. I am searching the literature for an order of magnitude of the absolute global concentration in the cytoplasm. Although I am aware this quantity can vary greatly from proteins to proteins, I would be happy if I find some papers having estimated it for some given proteins.

Comment: I guess you would want to exclude cytoskeletal proteins

Comment: Hard to find data for eukaryotes. For E coli some of these things have been measured and rough numbers have been made. I recommend the BioNumbers database as a great starting place: http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/default.aspx . In particular, look up the (famous) table linked to by Bio Number ID 102990. It lists that at exponential phase E coli has about $2.35\times10^6$ protein molecules of 1850 types, so about 1270 copies of each protein. E coli is about 1 $\mu$m$^3$, so that's a concentration of about 20$\mu$M per protein if my math is right. But that's bacteria which are very different.